# Turn on do not disturb programmatically, with exceptions

Tags: java, android, kotlin, do-not-disturb

I have an android app, and I need to turn on the Do Not Disturb button programmatically, but with exceptions, that I can play media. I did succeed with turning on the Do Not Disturb with this code :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted) {
        Log.d(Globals.LOG_TAG, "has permissions")
    } else {
        Log.d(Globals.LOG_TAG, "does not have permissions")
        val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
} else {
    Log.d(Globals.LOG_TAG, "device does not support do not disturb feature")
}
```

```
notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE)
```

and added the permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>
```

but couldn't play media on the app because of the Do Not Disturb. But I saw that I can set exceptions (for calls, alarms, media...), and I want to add an exception to media programmatically.

How can I achieve that? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to do

```
notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY)
```

instead of

```
notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE)
```